# Twig get url parameter with []

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have an url like : `MYURL?filter[_per_page]=25&filter[name][value]=hello`

How can i get these parameters with twig ?

I'm trying `{{ app.request.get('filter[_per_page]') }}` but it's always empty...

Thanks !

Edit : I'm in javascript an i want to assign this result to a javascript variable like : `var param = "{{ app.request.get('filter[_per_page]') }}";`

Comment: Are you trying to access the query parameters from a subrequest (i.e. embedding controller)?  try to call {{app.request.query.all}} and see what print. Hope this help.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You must manage as an array accessing to the `filter` element as:

```
{{ app.request.get('filter')['_per_page'] }}
```

(This time I try before posting...)

Comment: Sure ? ^^ Impossible to access a key ("_per_page") on a NULL variable

Comment: Very strange... I copy exactly your like. If I try with `{{ app.request.get('filter') }}` take the error : ` Array to string conversion` so I append the access array key element and print correclty `25`...

Comment: For me with just {{ app.request.get('filter') }} i have nothing, empty string again...

Comment: I try with the url: `http://spike.localhost/app_dev.php/issue?filter[_per_page]=25&filter[name][value]=hello`

Comment: Hi @ClémentAndraud, where was the mistake?

Comment: i was in a twig templace included in another... ^^

Answer (score 8):

You've almost got it.

`app` object is `GlobalVariables` instance. When you say `app.request`, `getRequest()` is being invoked and returns an instance of standard `Request` object.

Now if you look at `Request::get()` ([**link**](http://api.symfony.com/2.6/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html#method_get)) there is:

```
get(string $key, mixed $default = null, bool $deep = false)
```

I think what you need to do is this:

```
{{ app.request.get('filter[_per_page]', NULL, true) }}
```

Where `NULL` is default value and `true` means `deep` traversal of `Request` object.

Comment: No it's the same, i have an empty value

Answer (score 1):

To access to array of query params you can use:

```
app.request.attributes.get('_route_params');
```

You can see different solutions on the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/cmf/bundles/core/templating.html).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution like this :

```
app.request.attributes.get('request').query.get('param_name')
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.